# How to access the particular viewcontroller from the tabbarcontroller?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had an application in which i had a tabbarcontroller adding to the window of the application.In the tabbarcontroller i had two tab bar items each having  navigation controller,in which corresponding view controllers are connected.Now i need to access an instance variable of the particular view-controller which is inside the navigation controller in the tab bar controller.I am doing like this but of no use:

```
NSArray *mycontrollers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
NSLog(@"%@",mycontrollers);
self.secondviewcontroller=(SecondViewController *)[mycontrollers objectAtIndex:1];
self.secondviewcontroller.var=self.var;
```

But it has thrown some error message as

`-[UINavigationController setvar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` can anybody help me figuring out how to achive the particular view controller from the hirarchy of this navigationcontrollers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
NSArray *mycontrollers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
NSLog(@"%@",mycontrollers);
UINavigationController *nvc = [mycontrollers objectAtIndex:1];
self.secondviewcontroller=(SecondViewController *)[nvc topViewController];
self.secondviewcontroller.var=self.var;
```

The reason your app was crashing because `self.tabBarController.viewControllers;` was returning the navigation controllers.

Comment: throws me a warning navigationcontroller may not respond to objectatindex inthe 4 th line